# Adjective-Nominalization さの vs normal usage with な

Tags: grammar, meaning

I try reading a Japanese book for the first time and I have some trouble with the sentence:

> たったひとりとはいえ、その自分を惨めさの道連れにした。

I think I somewhat get the meaning of it, but I am confused why 惨め is nominalized instead of attaching the な particle.

Comment: `道通れ` -- 「[道連]{みちづ}れ」じゃなくて？ **連**じゃなくて**通** ？

Comment: @Chocolate, You are right, it's 道連れ. Thanks for pointing out. ... I am sorry, than it all makes sense.